# Cannot infer type when passing None to Option<impl FnMut()>

Tags: rust

I have something like this:

```
fn my_func(cb: Option<impl FnMut(i32) + 'static>) { ... }
```

If I try to pass in None, such as: `my_func(None)`, I get:

```
cannot infer type for type parameter `impl FnMut(i32) + 'static` declared on the method `my_func`
```

I found a previous post that said I still need to specify a type via `None::<T>` using something that implements `T`, and that makes sense, but how do I do that in this case? I tried defining an empty function that matches the signature, but that didn't work. Rust complained I wasn't passing in any "types", and I was passing too many "consts".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably tried to pass in an actual function instead of the *type* of a function. You can use `None::<fn(i32)>`, since `fn(i32)` is a concrete type that implements the `FnMut(i32) + 'static` trait bound.

[Link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6dc30b4edbd633996c65d282cb50a4d9)

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Comment: This should be a hint from the compiler instead, as the compiler's hint is useless and this actually works.