# Do I need to specify the type of None if the expected type is Optional<&impl MyTrait>?

Tags: rust

Here's an example, mostly taken from [The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html):

```
pub trait Summary {
    fn summarize(&self) -> String;
}

pub struct NewsArticle {
    pub headline: String,
    pub location: String,
    pub author: String,
    pub content: String,
}

impl Summary for NewsArticle {
    fn summarize(&self) -> String {
        format!("{}, by {} ({})", self.headline, self.author, self.location)
    }
}

pub struct Tweet {
    pub username: String,
    pub content: String,
    pub reply: bool,
    pub retweet: bool,
}

impl Summary for Tweet {
    fn summarize(&self) -> String {
        format!("{}: {}", self.username, self.content)
    }
}

fn myfunc(s: Option<&impl Summary>) {
    match s {
        Some(s) => println!("{:?}", s.summarize()),
        None => println!("nothing to summarize")
    }
}

fn main() {
    myfunc(None::<&NewsArticle>);  // works
    // myfunc(None); // fails
}
```

I've made my function `myfunc`, which I would like to accept a variable which is either `None`, or it can be a `Summary`.

If it's a `Summary`, then it calls `.summarize()` and prints it. If it's `None`, then it prints that there's nothing to summarise.

My question is - why can't I just call `myfunc(None)`? If I do that, the compiler tells me

```
39 |     myfunc(None);
   |            ^^^^ cannot infer type of the type parameter `T` declared on the enum `Option`
   |
help: consider specifying the generic argument
   |
39 |     myfunc(None::<&impl Summary>);
   |                +++++++++++++++++
```

Or is there a different way to declare `myfunc` such that `s` can be either `None` or a `Summary`?

EDIT:

I've been asked if [Cannot infer type when passing None to Option<impl FnMut()>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60685572/cannot-infer-type-when-passing-none-to-optionimpl-fnmut) answers my question. It doesn't, as I'm not trying to pass a type of a function.

Answer (score 2):

Rust generics are implemented by creating a different function for every combination of type parameters ([Monomorphization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomorphization)), to select the correct function all type parameters have to be known, and `Option::None` is generic so it doesn't provide a concrete type, that's why you have to provide one, so Rust can pick a concrete function to insert for your `myfunc` call.

Comment: thanks. So, I can just pass any of the types, it doesn't really matter which one?

Comment: That depends on what the function does, in your case yes it doesn't really matter since the path when called with `None` doesn't depend on the type parameter.